# how can i call fragment from listadapter

Tags: android

Hi i am calling fragment from my custom adapter but its displaying error can any one help me here is the MyListAdapter snippet

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final TextView view = new TextView(parent.getContext());
    view.setText(values.get(position));

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view1) {

            // Get the position
            Log.w(MyListAdapter.LOG_KEY, "MyListAdapter Lable Clicked");

            Intent intent= new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

and my SingleItemView.class

```
public class SingleItemView extends Fragment{

LinearLayout linearLayout;

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, container, false);

setHasOptionsMenu(true);

return linearLayout;
```

}
}

and here is the error message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NswIX.png)

Comment: Fragment can't add using intent.

Comment: have you initialise your context?

Comment: post your constructor code of adapter class

Answer (score 0):

You can not start `Fragment` by `Intent`. `Fragment` have to be hosted by any `Activity`. You have to navigate to this `Activity`.

If you want to start special `Fragment` in those `Activity` (for example any `Fragment` in `ViewPager`) put any flag in your `Intent`. By this flag in your `Activity` you can determine which `Fragment` should be started.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you can't call Fragments via Intent, Fragment is a part of an FragmentActivity

All in all Fragment is a content not container, so you need to create a FragmentActivity and add Fragment(Favourite) in that, and then call

Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, SomeFragmentActivity.class);

startActivity(intent1);

A Fragment is a piece of an application's user interface or behavior that can be placed in an Activity.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html